# GDM cannot show user after upgrade to 20.04

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 20.04, login, gdm

I just upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 on my workstation. It uses LDAP authentication. I already have an authenticated user. It used to be shown in GDM prior the upgrade. However after the upgrade only an admin account is shown.

I'm able to type in my username and password and can login. How can I make my user reappear in GDM? (I don't want to change GDM to lightDM)

Comment: What's the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.login-screen disable-user-list`?

Comment: `$ gsettings get org.gnome.login-screen disable-user-list`  
false

Comment: That's the correct value to show a user. So it's something else...

Comment: What does `nano greeter.dconf-defaults` tell you? Is there something activated under `# Login manager options` like `# disable-user-list=true`?

Comment: Checked `/etc/gdm3/greeter.dconf-defaults`. I don't see a non-commented-out line that starts with `disable-*`. Pasting content [here](https://dpaste.com/AQMQEUPEG). The one under `/usr/share/gdm/greeter.dconf-defaults` seems to have the same content.

Answer (score 1):

The solution (or band-aid) in my case was to disable a new SSSD service called NSS (see below). From what I understand this service helps to integrate AD account settings with Ubuntu user settings. There must be some kind of account setting in Active Directory that prevents the user accounts from being saved in the ubuntu user list. When I would navigate to settings>users none of the LDAP users were listed thus preventing them from being seen in GDM greeter.

Disabling SSSD NSS Service:

1. Open /etc/sssd/sssd.conf
2. Change services = nss, pam  to... services = pam
3. Optional - Add a comment to the file that describes your changes and why you make them.
4. Restart the PC

Further Reading:
https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-sssd-ldap

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: my user name does not appear when login after upgrade Ubuntu/ gdm3 from 20.04 to 22.04. It is in "not listed" user accounts. I click "not listed", can login.

Solved by changing my user account to regular and reinstalling gdm3

checked out solutions in but failed https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234452/ubuntu-20-04-user-not-listed-to-login

I found my user account was changed to SystemAccount=true in the file /var/lib/AccountsService/users/my_username.

Change to regular user account, which will be showed up when login.

1. sudo su
2. cd /var/lib/AccountsService/users
3. vim my_username
   change SystemAccount=true =>
   SystemAccount=false

failed to show up when login.

However Display Manager switched to lightdm or sddm, my user appears when login https://techpiezo.com/linux/switch-display-manager-in-ubuntu-22-04/

reinstall gdm3, solved my problem.

1. sudo apt purge gdm3
2. sudo apt install gdm3

Solved.