# User not showed in login

Tags: 20.04, login, gnome-terminal, users, ubuntu-gnome

A few days ago I tried to customize the gnome terminal and in trying to return to the default configuration I touched something too much.

At boot Ubuntu 20.04 forces me to create a new user as if it were the first time I use it and, as soon as it is created, in the login screen my original user is not listed, only the new one I created, and I can only access the original through the "not in list" button.

I tried to follow the solution publicated by Richard Haddad here:

[Ubuntu 20.04 user not listed to login](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234452/ubuntu-20-04-user-not-listed-to-login)

but did not resolve the problem.

I also tried to remove the user via:

```
sudo deluser --remove-home andre
```

where andre is the new user that ubuntu forced me to create, but nothing, at the reboot ubuntu necessarily wants to create a new user.  Any help to avoid reinstalling ubuntu?

PS: Could this problem be with the .bashrc home file?

EDIT: I resolved changing the value of my user line in file /etc/passwd/ from /bin/zsh to /bin/bash