# Set user SystemAccount to false

Tags: 20.04, gdm, accounts

I have the same problem [listed here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234452/ubuntu-20-04-user-not-listed-to-login).

But when I change the `SystemAccount` property to false and reboot, it is set back to true.

Even if I only logout the property is set back to true.

I also tried stopping the `account-service` and starting it back after changing the `/var/lib/AccountService/users/username` file with no luck.

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the solution was to change the user record in my `/etc/passwd` from:

`{user}:x:1001:1001::/home/{user}`

...to...

`{user}:x:1001:1001:{user},,,:/home/{user}:/bin/bash`