# missed username during login

Tags: command-line, 20.04, bash

Tried to install `oh-my-zsh` in Ubuntu 20.04 - without success. I rolled back all changes and switched to `bash` shell, but somehow I missed my username from startup.

Previously, I had my username pre-filled, and I needed only type my password. Now I need to type both. Maybe it's not related to shell changes, but I need a way to fix it. How can I change it back.

Answer (score 0):

Into `/var/lib/AccountsService/users`

`SystemAccount` flag was somehow setup to true, since I changed it to false and logged out the issue was fixed

Solution:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1263662/1199053